# Maximum recursion depth error with getattr

Tags: python, exception, recursion, descriptor

I have this code;

```
class NumberDescriptor(object):
    def __get__(self, instance, owner):
        name = (hasattr(self, "name") and self.name)
        if not name:
            name = [attr for attr in dir(owner) if getattr(owner,attr) is self][0]
            self.name = name
        return getattr(instance, '_' + name)
    def __set__(self,instance, value):
        name = (hasattr(self, "name") and self.name)
        if not name:
            owner = type(instance)
            name = [attr for attr in dir(owner) if getattr(owner,attr) is self][0]
            self.name = name
        setattr(instance, '_' + name, int(value))

class Insan(object):
    yas = NumberDescriptor()

a = Insan()
print a.yas
a.yas = "osman"
print a.yas
```

I am getting maximum recursion depth error in the line `name = [attr for attr in dir(owner) if getattr(owner,attr) is self][0]`. I want that line to get me the name of variable used for current descriptor instance. Can anyone see what am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The `getattr()` call is calling your `__get__`.

One way to work around this is to explicitly call through the superclass, `object`:

```
object.__getattribute__(instance, name)
```

Or, clearer:

```
instance.__dict__[name]
```

Comment: `instance.__dict__[name]` might fail for non-data descriptors in general case. `NumberDescriptor` is a data descriptor so it should work in this case.