# Using __getattr__ to call child methods for specific type?

Tags: python, python-2.7, recursion, getattr

I have a class who's fields are an instance of another class.

```
class Field:
    def get(self):
    def set(self, value):
    def delete(self):

class Document:
    def __init__(self):
        self.y = Field()
        self.z = True
```

What I'd like to be able to do is when an instance of the parent refers to its attributes, instead it calls the child's methods.

```
d = Document()
d.y = 'some value'  # Calls the `set` function of the Field
d.y == 'some value'  # Calls the `get` function of the Field
del d.y  # Calls the `delete` function of the Field
```

The other catch is that I only want this behavior when the field is of type `Field`.

I'm running into recursion problems try to use `__getattr__` and the like, along the lines of:

```
def __getattr__(self, key):
    if isinstance(getattr(self, key), Field):
        return getattr(self, key).get()
    return getattr(self, key)
```

The recursion is fairly obvious why its happening... but how do I avoid it?

I've seen a few examples already on StackOverflow, but I can't seem to figure out how to get around it.

- [Maximum recursion depth error with getattr](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12163476/maximum-recursion-depth-error-with-getattr)
- [Understanding the difference between __getattr__ and __getattribute__](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4295678/understanding-the-difference-between-getattr-and-getattribute)

Comment: Why not just use descriptors? This functionality is built in.

Comment: Wbat you're describing is pretty much exactly what descriptors are, except the method names are spelled `__get__`, `__set__` and `__delete__`, and the descriptor is set as an attribute of the class, not the instance.  I'd suggest you look at some info about descriptors (e.g., [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3798835/understanding-get-and-set-and-python-descriptors) and [here](http://nbviewer.ipython.org/urls/gist.github.com/ChrisBeaumont/5758381/raw/descriptor_writeup.ipynb)).

Comment: Thanks! I'll try that, see how it goes.

Comment: A side note idf you are nto using Python 3.x, always make your classes inherit from "object"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are describing there is more or less exactly the innerent way Python access attributes of a class with the Descriptor protocol -

Just make your field classes have a `__get__`, `__set__` and `__delete__` method as described in https://docs.python.org/2/howto/descriptor.html -- 
And be sure that all you classes have `object` as the base class, otherwise they inherit from old-style classes, that only exist in Python 2 for compatibility reasons, and are deprecated since Python 2.2  (and ignore completely the descriptor protocol)

Comment: Good callout on the base classes, I'm on 2.7.

Comment: Without using the descriptor" protocol, what you are asking could become quite advanced. Feasible, of course.