# Maximum recursion depth error in the python function

Tags: python, recursion, exception

I am getting maximum recursion depth error in the line `if hasattr(self, '_ubuffer')`. Can anyone see what am I doing wrong here? Whole code of the function is:

```
def __getattr__(self, name):
        if hasattr(self, '_ubuffer'):
            buffer = object.__getattribute__(self,'_ubuffer')
            if name in buffer.dtype.names:
                return buffer.data[name]
        return object.__getattribute__(self,name)
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Maximum recursion depth error with getattr](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12163476/maximum-recursion-depth-error-with-getattr)

Answer (score 6):

`hasattr` calls `__getattr__` which would cause the recursion. [From the docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#hasattr):

> `hasattr(object, name)` The arguments are an object and a string. The result is True if the string is the name of one of the object’s attributes, False if not. **(This is implemented by calling getattr(object, name) and seeing whether it raises an exception or not.)** [my emphasis]

One way to get around this problem might be to replace `if hasattr(self, '_ubuffer')` with something like `if '_ubuffer' in self.__dict__`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the superclass implementation for regular attribute access:

```
def __getattr__(self, name):
    try:
        buffer = super(MyClass, self).__getattr__('_ubuffer')
    except AttributeError:
        raise AttributeError('Attribute {} not found.'.format(name))

    if name in buffer.dtype.names:
        return buffer.data[name]
    else:
        raise AttributeError('Attribute {} not found.'.format(name))
```

Comment: I like this way more. It is less intrusive (no need to dig up internal `__dict__` attribute), it is more portable since it also works for classes using `__slots__` instead of `__dict__`, and it is faster (it is recommended to sure `try ... catch ...` blocks instead of `if ... else ...` if it is never supposed to fail).

Answer (score 1):

The method proposed by @maciej-gol is quite nice, but it does not handle the common case where the super class does not define custom `__getattr__` (at least for Python3). To avoid such issue, it is better to check first using `__getattribute__`, which is always defined, and to fallback to `_getattr_` if it fails.

I suggest doing this *if you don't know in advance if the base class implements a custom `__getattr__` method*:

```
def __getattr__(self, name):
    try:
        buffer = self.__getattribute__('_ubuffer')
    except AttributeError:
        try:
            buffer = super().__getattr__('_ubuffer')
        except AttributeError:
            raise AttributeError('Attribute {} not found.'.format(name))

    if name in buffer.dtype.names:
        return buffer.data[name]
    raise AttributeError('Attribute {} not found.'.format(name))
```

But in most cases, just using `__getattribute__` should be enough:

```
def __getattr__(self, name):
    try:
        buffer = self.__getattribute__('_ubuffer')
        if name in buffer.dtype.names:
            return buffer.data[name]
        raise AttributeError
    except AttributeError:
        raise AttributeError('Attribute {} not found.'.format(name))
```